# Short story about a man who goes to get his memory erased after falling in love with a girl but getting separated from her

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this short story years ago about a couple who meet, then are separated. The guy searches for the girl, but never finds her. In the end, to escape the torture of her memory, he goes to a place that erases selected memories, only to see the girl walking out, having just had the procedure herself. Sad, poignant, and similar to the plot of "Spotless Mind".

Comment: This is a nice description but can you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) to see if there is anything else you can [edit] in? For example, do you know when you read this, i.e. how long ago was "years ago"? Was it new at the time?

Comment: Sorry, Carrot, I'm 61 and my memory isn't as formidable as it once was...that's about all I remember.

Comment: DannyMcG...not familiar with that story.

Comment: Does [this](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/15733511-the-memory-eater) look familiar?

Comment: Don't think so, interesting looking anthology, but I don't remember it. Seems like it was in one of those collections of "best" anthologies, and I could have sworn when "Sunshine" came out, the movie was based on it.

Comment: "Hearts Do Not in Eyes Shine" by John Kessel is about a couple and selective memory erasure, but the rest of your plot description does not match.

Comment: That sounds familiar, I'll look into it, thanks Ubik!

Comment: Read it...good story, but not the one I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Could you be thinking of the movie Eternal Sunshine of the Spotless Mind starring Jim Carrey? It seems pretty identical to your description  and the writer, Charlie Kaufman, won the Academy Award for Best Original Screenplay.

Comment: I've honestly never seen the movie, but it was the synopsis of it that triggered the question. My understanding is the film was based on a novel, and the short story was always my preferred (although not exclusive) format for reading Science Fiction.